# emacs (exwm) freezing when inputing accented letters

Tags: keymap, exwm

I'm currently running a new install of exwm on a french laptop. Writing in french means I need to input accents. Those letters I can input using dead keys without any problem but I cannot use the actual pre accented letters (é,è,ç,ù,à) which is quite hard on my muscle memory.

Here's where the weird things start to show up.

If emacs hasn't frozen yet, I can input `C-é`, `C-è`, `C-ç`, `C-à` and `C-ù` without it freezing. I get a message in the minibuffer saying that these are not bound to any command which is normal.

I tried using `ltrace -p <emacs PID>` and while this is running (in a different  tty) emacs will not freeze but I cannot run it in backgroung in a dynamic way because the PID varies from one session to another. A soon as I stop ltrace, emacs freezes whatever the input. As soon as I start ltrace (after a freeze) everythings starts working again and my keystrokes all happen in order.

My XKbMap is set to pc105 fr latin9 which is the same as with my other window manager (herbstluftwm) which works fine. As for the emacs input method, I've left the default value which works fine if I start emacs in another window manager.

I am using the default config for exwm with the added line setting my XKbMap just before runing exwm.

2019-10-17 : Il seems the problem is linked to my vconsole.conf. If set to `KEYMAP=fr` exwm works as intended. If set to `KEYMAP=fr-latin1` , my actual layout, it starts freezing again.

Comment: What are these accented characters bound to? You should be able to check it if you start Emacs while running a different window manager.

Comment: If I run emacs in another window manager, the characters work just fine. Same as when running ltrace.

Comment: Does it hang when you're editing a buffer in Emacs or only in X clients?

Comment: Whatever the buffer I'm in it hangs. I tried Midori , Firefox and Urxvt as well as a Markdown file and a tex file. It also does it in read-only buffers such as the fancy-splash-screen

Comment: After switching from Parabola to Arch32 (linux-lible to linux), the error has disappeared. It's not a solution but my problem is gone

Comment: My previous comment misdiagnosed the origin of the error. It was not the kernel change but a configuration difference detailed at the end of the original post